# C++ correct use of stringstream::str()?

Tags: c++, stringstream

Consider the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    string l1, l2;
    int n1, n2;
    stringstream ss;
    getline(cin, l1);
    getline(cin, l2);
    cerr << l1 << " " << l2 << endl;
    ss.str(l1);
    ss >> n1;
    ss.str(l2);
    ss >> n2;
    cerr << n1 << " " << n2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
2
3
```

Corresponding output:

```
2 3
2 0
```

But I was expecting:

```
2 3
2 3
```

If I insert a call ss.clear() before the second call to ss.str(), the output is what I expected. Is this really necessary? And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary, because the first input from the stringstring hits end of file.  Calling `str()` does not clear any error flags that are already set on the stringstream.

```
 ss.str(l1);
 ss >> n1; // Reads the entire buffer, hits the end of buffer and sets eof flag
 ss.str(l2); // Sets the string, but does not clear error flags
 ss >> n2; // Fails, due to at EOF
```

You can use clear before the second str() or after, just as long as it's before you attempt to read more data.